# Laravel Custom Validation with Array as Parameter

Tags: laravel

Newbie here. Can anyone help me about getting the parameter in my custom validation.

Here is my validation rule :

```
['materials.*.receive_quantity' => 'lessthan:materials.*.quantity']
```

Here is my custom validation :

```
Validator::extend('lessthan', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) { return $value <= $parameters[0]; });
```

When i `dd($parameters)` it return a string **'materials.*.quantity'**. TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need a 5.4.18 release.
Then, try this code:

```
Validator::extendDependent('lessthan', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    return $value <= array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[0]);
});
```

And you may look at this pull request for more explanations and examples: [PR#18564](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18654)

P.S. And may be this is a typo in your code: your rule name is "lessthan", but you use the "<=" operator instead of "<".